# Gulp with TypeDoc errors out

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-typedoc

Good time of the day every body,

I have created a gulp task that should create tsdocs, here is what it looks like.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    helpers = require('../helpers/gulp-helpers')(),
    plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    env = require('./gulp.env');

function typedoc() {


    return gulp.src([
        'src/scripts/**/*!(.spec).ts',
        '!src/scripts/**/*.spec.ts',
        ...env.settings.typings
    ]).pipe(plugins.typedoc({
        module: 'commonjs',
        target: 'es5',
        experimentalDecorators: true,
        ignoreCompilerErrors: false,
        version: true,
        out: 'docs'
    })).on("error", (error) => {
        if (error.plugin && error.message) {
            // it is a gulp plugin error
            helpers.log("Error in plugin: " + error.plugin);
            helpers.log(error.message);
        }
        else {
            // some other error
            helpers.log(error);
        }
        exitCode++;
    }) // make exit code non-zero
}

// Workaround: directly calling process.exit() has corner cases where
// the console.log statements are not flushed (namely if stdout is piped
// instead of goes to a terminal).
let exitCode = 0;
process.on("exit", function() {
    if (exitCode != 0) process.exit(exitCode);
});


gulp.task('ts:docs', typedoc);
```

When I run it, it fails, with this error list:

```
TypeDoc 0.3.12
Using TypeScript 1.6.2 from /Users//private/cms/node_modules/typedoc/node_modules/typescript/lib

[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(84)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(179)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(180)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(181)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(182)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(183)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(184)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(226)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(227)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(228)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(229)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(230)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(471)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(472)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(473)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(474)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(475)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(476)
 Type expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1836)
 '=' expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1837)
 '=' expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1838)
 '=' expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1838)
 '=' expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1848)
 '=' expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1849)
 '=' expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1850)
 '=' expected.
[11:04:35] /Users//private/cms/typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1850)
 '=' expected.
[11:04:35] Error in plugin: gulp-typedoc
[11:04:35] Failed to generate load TypeDoc project.
[11:04:35] 'ts:docs' errored after 889 ms
[11:04:35] Error in plugin 'gulp-typedoc'
Message:
    Failed to generate load TypeDoc project.
```

Answer (score 4):

`Typedoc` is not updated the `typescript`'s (dependency module) `npm` version. so you just open the `typedoc` folder which is available in the `node_modules` folder in your project and edit the `package.json` file as follows.

`"typescript": "1.6.2"` to `"typescript": "1.8.10"`

then run the `npm i` command against `typedoc` project.

after that you can run your docs generation script. It will work fine.